# Vote Model Operations causing unknown troubles

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I made a Vote model given below. My blog model has two operations that upvotes or downvotes the specific blog. 
For example, When a single user upvotes, the votes field in Blog increases and a UserVote Model has a record of it and when the same user downvotes, it changes it's vote_type and updates the record.

The problem comes in when a second user casts a vote. After an upvote, when the second user downvotes, it says that he has already voted (although it should've changed his vote_type to downvote)

I've been going through this problem and I can't find a solution of it anywhere.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def upvote(self, user):
    try:
        if UserVote.objects.filter(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='down').exists():
            self.post_votes.update(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='up')
            self.votes += 2

        else:
            self.post_votes.create(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='up')
            self.votes += 1

        self.save()

    except IntegrityError:
        return 'already_voted'

    return 'ok'

def downvote(self, user):
    try:
        if UserVote.objects.filter(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='up').exists():
            self.post_votes.update(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='down')
            self.votes -= 2

        else:
            self.post_votes.create(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='down')
            self.votes -= 1

        self.save()

    except IntegrityError:
        return 'already_voted'

    return 'ok'

class UserVote(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='user_votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='post_votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
vote_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'blog', 'vote_type')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you can have one UserVote object per User/Blog/VoteType-combination.

Specifically, in the following lines

```
self.post_votes.update(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='up')

self.post_votes.update(user=user, blog=self, vote_type='down')
```

you are trying to update **all** vote objects that exist for the current blog to one of the vote_types. That means you potentially try to modify two UserVotes to have the exact same user, blog and vote_type, which causes an IntegrityError.

Thus, I would suggest only ever having one UserVote per User/Blog-combination instead of per User/Blog/VoteType-combination, i.e. change the unique_together to

```
unique_together = ('user', 'blog')
```

Then, you just have to change the type of the vote if the user has already voted on that blog. This prevents having an upvote and a downvote from the same user for the same blog at a time.

Also, you do not have to manually keep track of the total of upvotes and downvotes, you can get them straight from the count of UserVote objects. My suggested models.py looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def votes(self):
        upvotes = UserVote.objects.filter(blog=self, vote_type='up').count()
        downvotes = UserVote.objects.filter(blog=self, vote_type='down').count()
        return upvotes - downvotes

    def upvote(self, user):
        vote, created = UserVote.objects.get_or_create(user=user, blog=self)
        if not created and vote.vote_type == 'up':
            return 'already_voted'
        vote.vote_type = 'up'
        vote.save()
        return 'ok'

    def downvote(self, user):
        vote, created = UserVote.objects.get_or_create(user=user, blog=self)
        if not created and vote.vote_type == 'down':
            return 'already_voted'
        vote.vote_type = 'down'
        vote.save()
        return 'ok'


class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='user_votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='post_votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'blog')
```

I'm sure there is a much more clever way to get the total of upvotes and downvotes using [aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/), this is just a quick working example.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.
Thank you so much man! Much Respect and an upvote! <3

Comment: I messed up in between while working on this model and changed ```unique_together = ('user', 'blog', 'vote_type')``` by mistake. Just want to know what was wrong with the filter approach? It had me worried for hours.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the problem with your approach (hopefully) more clearly.

Comment: Thank you for such quick replies! Totally cleared my confusion! :D